Intersection form on complex algebraic surface
Let $X$ be a smooth connected complex algebraic surface. I read online that something called an intersection pairing on $H_2(X;\Bbb Z)$ forms a invariant of $X$. Could someone here shed some light on what is meant by the intersection pairing in this case and how should one view it as an invariant? I guess we have a bilinear form $$H_2(X;\Bbb Z) \times H_2(X,\Bbb Z) \to \Bbb C$$ but how is this defined? Also since Poincaré duality gives $H_2(X,\Bbb Z) \cong H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$, does this bilinear form give something on the level of cohomology also?
